# Can two measurements be represented as a single measurement when they are acted upon sequentially?

Tags: measurement, quantum-operation, povm

Let two different POVM measurements represent as $\mathcal{M}_1=\{\Pi_i\}_{i=1}^k$ where $\Pi_i$ is element of the $\mathcal{M}_1$ measurement and   $\mathcal{M}_2=\{E_j\}_{j=1}^n$ where $E_j$ is the element of the $\mathcal{M}_2$ measurement. Remember that each element of the two measurements do not commute i.e. $[\Pi_i,E_j]\neq0$. Now two measurements $\mathcal{M}_1$ and $\mathcal{M}_2$ act one after the other on the state $\rho$. So after post-processing, the first measurement $\mathcal{M}_1$ the unnormalized post-measurement state will be (using Lüders rule)
$$\rho^{\prime}_{ij}=\sqrt{E_j}\sqrt{\Pi_i}\rho\sqrt{\Pi_i^{\dagger}}\sqrt{E_j^{\dagger}}$$
Can these two measurements be represented as a single measurement when they are acted upon sequentially?

Comment: what do you mean with "post-processing" here?

Comment: After applying the measurement element $\Pi_i$ from the first measurement $\mathcal{M}_1$,  then  I apply another measurement element $E_j$ from the second measurement $\mathcal{M}_2$

Comment: $\sqrt{X^\dagger}$ is a bit redundant. You typically only define the matrix square root for positive semidefinite matrices which are self-adjoint. Also how are you defining the state update?

Comment: When a POVM element acts on a quantum state, one of the possible post-measurement states can be determined using the Lüders rule.

Comment: By Lüders rule you mean $\rho \mapsto X^{1/2} \rho X^{1/2}$ for some POVM element $X\geq 0$?

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: Well in that exact context it clearly isn't possible, the state update that you have asked for is $\rho \mapsto \sqrt{E_i}\sqrt{\Pi_j}\rho \sqrt{\Pi_j}\sqrt{E_i}$. But for that to be a Luders update, i.e. of the form $X^{1/2}\rho X^{1/2}$ you need $\sqrt{E_i}\sqrt{\Pi_j} = \sqrt{\Pi_j} \sqrt{E_i}$ which is only true if $[E_i, \Pi_j]=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you perform a POVM $\{\Pi_i\}_{i=1}^k$, and the associated post-measurement states conditionally to the $i$-th outcome are given by the maps $\rho\mapsto \sqrt{\Pi_i}\rho \sqrt{\Pi_i}$. You can describe this concisely saying you're dealing with a channel of the form
$$\Phi(\rho) = \sum_{i=1}^k \mathbb{P}_i\otimes \sqrt{\Pi_i}\rho \sqrt{\Pi_i} \qquad \mathbb{P}_i\equiv |i\rangle\!\langle i|.$$
Now you're performing another measurement $\{E_j\}_{j=1}^n$. Clearly, this measurement is performed on the states $\sqrt{\Pi_i}\rho \sqrt{\Pi_i}/\operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{\Pi_i}\rho \sqrt{\Pi_i})$ resulting from the first one, so the outcomes will be labeled by both $i$ and $j$, and the probability of getting the $(i,j)$-th outcome is
$$p_{ij}(\rho) = \operatorname{tr}(E_j \sqrt{\Pi_i}\rho \sqrt{\Pi_i})
= \operatorname{tr}(\sqrt{\Pi_i} E_j\sqrt{\Pi_i} \rho).$$
In other words, the POVM describing this "subsequent measurements" procedure is the one with operators
$$\mu_{ij} \equiv \sqrt{\Pi_i} E_j \sqrt{\Pi_i}.$$

You can also get to this more concisely by thinking in terms of the Kraus operators corresponding to the channels describing the measurements. The possible (unnormalized) states resulting from the first measurement are obtained applying the Kraus operators $\sqrt{\Pi_i}$ to the initial state. For the second measurement, you then apply $\sqrt{E_j}$, and thus the Kraus operators for the combined channel are $A_{ij}\equiv\sqrt{E_j}\sqrt{\Pi_i}$, and the corresponding POVM is the one with elements $\mu_{ij}=A_{ij}^\dagger A_{ij} = \sqrt{\Pi_i} E_j \sqrt{\Pi_i}$.

For yet another perspective, let's relax the requirement that post-measurement outcomes are given as $\sqrt{\Pi_i}\rho\sqrt{\Pi_i}$, and suppose the first measurement is described by a generic [quantum instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_instrument)
$$\Phi(\rho) = \sum_i \mathbb{P}_i\otimes \Phi_i(\rho),$$
with $\Phi_i$ trace-decreasing maps returning the post-measurement states corresponding to the $i$-th outcome.
The corresponding POVM operators are given by $\Pi_i = \Phi_i^\dagger(I)$ (equivalently, given the POVM $\{\Pi_i\}$, the set of possible maps describing post-measurement states satisfy this relation).
So now performing a second measurement with operators $\{E_j\}$, the probabilities are
$$p_{ij}(\rho) = \operatorname{tr}(E_j \Phi_i(\rho))
= \operatorname{tr}(\Phi_i^\dagger(E_j) \rho).$$
In other words, the POVM describing the subsequence measurements has elements
$$\mu_{ij} = \Phi_i^\dagger(E_j),$$
which you can easily see to be consistent with the previously obtained result when $\Phi_i(X)\equiv \sqrt{\Pi_i}X\sqrt{\Pi_i}$.

This formalism also gives you an elegant way to state the more general result: if you're doing a sequence of measurements, with the $k$-th measurement corresponding to the maps $\Phi^{(k)}$, then the overall measurement has elements
$$\mu_I = (\Phi_{I_1}^{(1)})^\dagger \circ \cdots \circ(\Phi_{I_K}^{(K)})^\dagger (E_{I_{K+1}} ),$$
with $K+1$ the overall number of measurements, and $E_j$ the elements of the very last one.
You can also easily interpret this relation as amounting to a "Heisenberg picture" applied to channels and measurements.